# Cascading style sheet (CSS)

Tags: html, css

What are the differences between dot and hash tag in CSS?
Code

```
.img{
    background:red;
    margin-top:2px;
}
#img{
    background:yellow;
    margin-top:2px;
```

Answer (score -1):

The dot ( . ) signifies a class name while the hash ( # ) signifies an element with a specific id attribute

**#img{}** will style the single element declared with an attribute **id="img" 

.img{}** will style all elements with an attribute **class="img"**